# The old name of domain group shows up always

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, groups

We granted permissions to group1 on a site collection. After a while we created a new OU on AD and moved group1 to this OU and renamed the group to group1New. However we still get the old name of the group (group1) when we want to grant permissions to this group on our site collections. We have followed this article

http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2011/12/updating-sharepoint-2010-user-information/

and tested to rename the group name in "User information List", tried to delete the group from User Information list, but still the old name appears. even on those site collections that we never added this group before. we have full synchronized many times but we always get old name. we appreciate any kind of advice.

Answer (score 1):

This is because it is a display name field that isn't in the sync data.

Only the group ID is used so the sync and permissions WILL still work regardless.

The code to rename the group will be something like:

```
SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups["Group by Name"];
SPListItem groupListItem = web.SiteUserInfoList.GetItemById(group.ID);
groupListItem["Name"] = "New Name";
groupListItem.Update();
```

Or for simplicity you can use [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com) browse to the group and rename it through the UI.

Comment: thank, I will test it and will be back.